# Regex for Aadhar card is throwing an error

Tags: formula-field, validation-rule, validation, regular-expressions

used this for validating Aadhar card

```
NOT(REGEX(Aadhar_Number__c , "[0-9]{12}"))
```

and I'm getting this error

> Incorrect argument type for function 'REGEX()'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this validation rule formula:

```
OR(
    LEN( Aadhar_Number__c ) <> 12,
    NOT( REGEX( Aadhar_Number__c, "^[0-9]+$"))
)
```

The `LEN` function can check the length of the field value and the `REGEX` function check whether the field has only a number or not.

Reference document:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_len.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

The inputs of [REGEX](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5) function must be of type `Text`, so if you provide it with a custom field that isn't a text field (most likely the type of `Aadhar_Number__c` is `Number`) you'll get that error message

> Incorrect argument type for function 'REGEX()'.

To fix the issue you could use the [TEXT()](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_text.htm&type=5) function, which converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field into text anywhere formulas are used.

Try:

```
NOT( REGEX( TEXT(Aadhar_Number__c) , '[0-9]{12}') )
```